# How to append cut text to nano/vi's clipboard/buffer instead of replacing what's there?

Tags: linux, vim, clipboard, nano

I'm currently reorganizing the ArchLinux pacman mirrors list to put all United States servers at the top, but it's going extremely slowly. For every single server I am scrolling down to the next US server on the list, cutting it, going back to the top, pasting it, and so on.

I feel like there should be some way for me to start from the bottom, and cut every US server I see into a cumulative buffer, before pasting all of it at once into the top of the file.

I know that Nano lets you use the cut command multiple times to add multiple times to the cutbuffer, but that is only for lines that are directly next to each other.

Comment: Not an answer to your (interesting) question have you considered using [Reflector](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Reflector) to extract US mirrors and sort them by rate rather than editing yourself?  For example `reflector --country 'United States' --latest 200 --age 24  --sort rate --save /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`

Answer (score 1):

In Vim, you can use [`:global`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Aglobal) to [`:move`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Amove) all matching lines to the top:

```
:global/United States/move 0
```

Note that this will reverse the order of the moved lines, though.

---

Another approach more in line with what you're asking is cutting the lines into a *named register* ([`:help quote_alpha`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#quote_alpha)). The uppercase variants append and therefore accumulate deletions:

```
:let @a = "" | global/United States/delete A
```

You can then paste the register at the top (this time with the original ordering):

```
:0put a
```